# Unable to expand more... python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I can scrape all the reviews from the web page.But I am not getting full content.Only half review content i can scrape.I need to scrape the full content.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup import requests import re


s = requests.Session()

def get_soup(url):

    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0'}

    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)

    #with open('temp.html', 'wb') as f:
    #    f.write(r.content)
    #    webbrowser.open('temp.html')

    if r.status_code != 200:
        print('status code:', r.status_code)
    else:
        return BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
     def parse(url, response):

    if not response:
        print('no response:', url)
        return

    # get number of reviews
#    num_reviews = response.find('span', class_='reviews_header_count').text
#    num_reviews = num_reviews[1:-1] # remove `( )`
#    num_reviews = num_reviews.replace(',', '') # remove `,`
#    num_reviews = int(num_reviews)
#    print('num_reviews:', num_reviews, type(num_reviews))

    num_reviews = (20)
#    num_reviews = num_reviews[1:-1] # remove `( )`
#    num_reviews = num_reviews.replace(',', '') # remove `,`
#    num_reviews = int(num_reviews)
    print('num_reviews:', num_reviews, type(num_reviews))

    # create template for urls to pages with reviews
    url = url.replace('Hilton_New_York_Grand_Central-New_York_City_New_York.html', 'or{}-Hilton_New_York_Grand_Central-New_York_City_New_York.html')
    print('template:', url)

    # add requests to list
    for offset in range(0, num_reviews, 5):
        print('url:', url.format(offset))
        url_ = url.format(offset)
        parse_reviews(url_, get_soup(url_))
        #return # for test only - to stop after first page

def parse_reviews(url, response):
    print('review:', url)

    if not response:
        print('no response:', url)
        return

    for idx, review in enumerate(response.find_all('div', class_='review-container')):
        item = {
            'hotel_name': response.find('h1', class_='heading_title').text,
            'review_title': review.find('span', class_='noQuotes').text,
            'review_body': review.find('p', class_='partial_entry').text,
            'review_date': review.find('span', class_='relativeDate')['title'],#.text,#[idx],
#            'num_reviews_reviewer': review.find('span', class_='badgetext').text,
            'reviewer_name': review.find('span', class_='scrname').text,
            'bubble_rating': review.select_one('div.reviewItemInline span.ui_bubble_rating')['class'][1][7:],
        }
        #~ yield item

        results.append(item) 

        for key,val in item.items():
            print(key, ':', val)
        print('----')
        #return # for test only - to stop after first review
         start_urls = [
    'https://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g60763-d93339-Reviews-Hilton_New_York_Grand_Central-New_York_City_New_York.html',
    #'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g60795-d102542-Reviews-Courtyard_Philadelphia_Airport-Philadelphia_Pennsylvania.html',
    #'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g60795-d122332-Reviews-The_Ritz_Carlton_Philadelphia-Philadelphia_Pennsylvania.html', ]

results = [] 

for url in start_urls:
    parse(url, get_soup(url))

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(results) # <--- convert list to DataFrame df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

I am getting an output sample in csv file from review like:

```
I went on a family trip and it was amazing, I hope to come back soon. The room was small but what can you expect from New York. It was close to many things and the staff was perfect.I will come back again soon.More...
```

I just want to expand that more. I need a help..I really have no clue to do it.Please help.

I have written one more code but unable to pull the id from next page.Code is given below

```
import re
import urllib
#import webbrowser``

s = requests.Session()

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0'}

for i in range(0,10,5):
    url = ("https://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g60763-d93339-Reviews-or{}-Hilton_New_York_Grand_Central-New_York_City_New_York.html").format(i)
    print(url)
    r = s.get(url,headers=headers)
    html = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    pattern = re.compile(r"UID_(\w+)\-SRC_(\w+)")
    id = soup.find("div", id=pattern)["id"]
    uid = pattern.match(id).group(2)
    print(uid)
    url1 ="https://www.tripadvisor.in/ShowUserReviews-g60763-d93339-r"+str(uid)+"-Hilton_New_York_Grand_Central-New_York_City_New_York.html#CHECK_RATES_CONT"
    print(url1)
    url2 = ('"' + url1 + '"')`enter code here`
    print(url2)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clearer what you're asking. Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks for you advice..I have clicked a new page which url is "tripadvisor.in/… while clicked on the next page, "/ShowUserReviews-g304558-d1312478-r557236838"...This ids got changed..How to automate that?the value for r557236838 got change..next url i got r555565913...this is not a structured one..how to change it automatically???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site uses ajax to expand the review content. The full content is not downloaded until the `More` link is clicked.

One way to access the content would be to figure out the ajax request format and then issue a HTTP request for the same. That might be difficult, perhaps not.

Another, easier, way is by noticing that the review title is a clickable link which loads the full review in a new page. You can therefore scrape the URL for each review and send a similar `GET` request. Then scrape the data from the response.

Comment: thanks for you advice..I have clicked a new page which url is "https://www.tripadvisor.in/ShowUserReviews-g304558-d1312478-r557236838-Park_Prime_Kolkata-Kolkata_Calcutta_Kolkata_District_West_Bengal.html#CHECK_RATES_CONT"....Now while clicked on the next page, "/ShowUserReviews-g304558-d1312478-r557236838"...This ids got changed..How to automate that?

Comment: the value for r557236838 got change..next url i got r555565913...this is not a structured one..how to change it automatically???